# Sql server: create a trigger after update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have 3 tables:

- Artist = {artistname, members}
- Musician = {msin, firstname, lastname}
- Plays = {artistname, msin}

Key:

- Artist: artistname
- Musician: msin
- Play: artistname (foreign key ref Artist), msin (foreign key ref Musician)

Other Information:

- Artist is the Band Name, Members records the number of musicians in the band.
- msin is the ID number of Musician.
- Play records which musician play in which Band/Artist

I need to create a trigger on Plays table: The members attribute of the Artist table should always equal the number of musicians who are members of the Artist. Any insertion, deletion, update in Plays triggers the changes of members attribute in Musician.

I did these in for deletion and insertion:

```
create trigger memberAddDel
on Plays
after insert, delete
as
if exists ( select 1 from inserted ) and not exists ( select 1 from deleted )
begin
    update Artist
    set members = (select count(msin) 
                    from Plays p 
                    group by p.artistname 
                    having p.artistname = (select artistname from inserted))
    where artistname = (select artistname from inserted)
end 
else if exists ( select 1 from deleted ) and not exists ( select 1 from inserted ) 
begin
    update Artist
    set members = (select count(msin) 
                    from Plays p 
                    group by p.artistname 
                    having p.artistname = (select artistname from deleted))
    where artistname = (select artistname from deleted)
end
```

But I am stuck with the update part. My understanding is when updating a table, the query creates an inserted and deleted table. inserted is the new record, and deleted is the old record. I considered following situation:

- updates in msin in Plays only: count msin again of that artistname
- updates in artistname in Plays only: count msin again of both artistname (in inseserted and deleted)
- updates in artistname and msin : count msin again of both artistname (in inseserted and deleted)

This is my try: I just update both artistnames associated members very brutally.

```
create trigger memberUpdate
on Plays
after update
as
if exists ( select 1 from inserted ) and exists ( select 1 from deleted )
begin
    update Artist 
    set members = (select count(msin) 
                    from Plays p 
                    group by artistname 
                    having artistname = (select artistname from inserted)
    where artistname = (select artistname from inserted)

    update Artist 
    set members = (select count(msin) 
                    from Plays p 
                    group by artistname 
                    having artistname = (select artistname from deleted)
    where artistname = (select artistname from deleted)

end
```

I have Zero experience creating triggers. This is my question: Is this the correct way to handle update triggers? Is this query even correct? or any cleaner way to write this trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One remark first, the `having` and `where` condition are not correct: `select artistname from inserted` could contain several rows.

Also, we could argue that having a specific column to count the members is not really needed since this information can be calculated at anytime. But this choice may be relevant to improve performance in your case, it's up to you.

Here is what I suggest to update the members based on `INSERTED` and `DELETED`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER memberUpdate
ON Plays
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE A SET members = A2.members
    FROM Artist A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT A.artistname, A.members + COUNT(I.msin) - COUNT(D.msin) AS members
        FROM Artist A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN inserted I ON A.artistname = I.artistname
            LEFT OUTER JOIN deleted D ON A.artistname = D.artistname
        WHERE 
            --exclude artists that have not been updated
            I.artistname IS NOT NULL OR D.artistname IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY A.artistname, A.members) AS A2
    ON A.artistname = A2.artistname
END
```

Comment: Very smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I can see if that you expect the number of band members to be stored in the bands table, which you already know it's bound to change.

If I were you, I'd simply use the `Play` table to find out how many members a band has. Keep in mind that you might need to keep track of "fluid" bands, where members come and leave. So you might want to add a `DateFrom` and `DateTo` column for that purpose.

You can then find the accurate number of members in a band at any point in time by querying the Play table using the desired date.